# Python error in creating serial port

Tags: python, pyserial

I am having a problem in running a python script. The python script reads a serial port. When running a script I am getting following error

```
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 268, in flushInput
 if not self.hComPort: raise portNotOpenError
 ValueError: Attempting to use a port that is not open
```

My python script to create a serial port is

```
ser = serial.Serial(11, 115200,timeout=1)
ser.setWriteTimeout(1)
print ser.portstr
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()
```

I am getting error in `ser.flushInput()`

Can anyone let me know why is this error generating and how to resolve this?

Comment: what does `print ser.portstr` print?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to let program to check if port open or not.

```
if ser.isOpen():
    print("Port: " + ser.portstr + " is open.\n")
```